# Cassandra random key (?)

Tags: cassandra

I an currently a MongoDB user but,

seen the lack of a random function (to get *n* random keys from the db), I was thinking about switching to cassandra.

I have read a bit about it and might be suitable for what I need; although I have not found anything regarding getting random keys, if that is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible
You have to write it yourself